# Open all html links in one destination tab without creating multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have multiple links that when clicked opens a video file. Now, I know that if I want to open a video file in a new tab, I would have something like:

```
<a href="../video.jsp" target="_blank">Link to Video</a>
```

But I have multiple links and I do not want each one of the links to create a new tab separately. Instead, all the links should point to one destination tab i.e., When I click a first link, it should open the video file in a new tab, say "TabNew". Now, I click a different link, this link should refresh and load the new content in the "TabNew" tab instead of creating an other tab.

Is there any way to do this using HTML, or jQuery etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of _blank, use a specific name (i.e., ... href="../video.jsp" target="GSM">Link to Video...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had already tried the same exact thing. Created a new blank html file and pointed the target to the new html file and its works! :)